# WooCommerce $_product->is_visible() error - cart.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

normally the permalink/link to the product isn't available if one sets the catalog visibility to hidden. (Not the woocommerce plugin just on the product page)

Now this works for some products but some are still showing up with a link in the cart view.

I open up the cart.php and var_dump this:

```
$_product->is_visible()
```

above:

```
$product_permalink = apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink($cart_item) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key);
```

Now also the products with catalog visibility set to hidden return true and have a permalink so I think there is something wrong with the filter?

Any suggestions?

Edit 1:
If I do it like that it works like expected and no link is inserted:

```
$isVisibleInCatalog = get_post_meta($product_id, '_visibility', true);
                    if ($isVisibleInCatalog != 'hidden') {
                        $product_permalink = apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink($cart_item) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key);
                    } else {
                        $product_permalink = "";
                    }
```

Edit 2:

WordPress 4.7.3

WooCommerce 2.6.14

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: There is no error. It shows a link instead of not showing a link. so the $product_permalink should be empty if you set the catalog visibility in the admin panel to hidden.

Comment: what don't try: `$bool = WC_Product::is_visible();` instead of custom post meta?

Comment: This is the official post meta for the visibility. Your is_visible() method is called in the filter but gives true instead of false

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which Woocommerce version you are using. You need to use

`WC_Product::is_visible();`

Comment: There's no problem using `$_product->is_visible()` if `$_product` is an instance of `WC_Product`